# Deployment of ASP.NET MVC 4 web application with Entity Framework Code First approach

Tags: entity-framework, svn, asp.net-mvc-4, web-deployment

I want to make incremental releases of a web application implemented in ASP.NET using MVC 4 and Entity Framework Code-First.

I want to make a good and safe deployment routine. I currently use Subversion as source control, and plan to make releasable tags available on the SVN server, to deploy on the production server. The server runs on a separate network, but has access to the SVN server.

The server runs both IIS and MSSQL server.

1. What is the best way to deploy new releases to the production server using SVN? Prebuilt binaries or build on site.
2. How to handle model changes on the production server? On development I use Update-Database function on the Package Manager Consol in Visual Studio.

EDIT:

I will try to base my setup on this blog post, which uses git instead of SVN: http://www.jayway.com/2012/10/17/a-simple-continuous-integration-and-deployment-workflow-with-asp-net-mvc-github-and-jenkins/

But still all suggestions are very welcome.